# How to use Maven, Jenkins Pipeline and Artifactory?

Tags: maven, jenkins, plugins, jenkins-pipeline, artifactory

I have a large, complex project, driven by Maven, built by Jenkins and reposing in Artifactory.
Projects are configured as multi-branch pipelines, and Jenkinsfiles are working.
I have been using the Jenkins Artifactory plugin with success. When a job is run (via the SCM trigger or directly) it all works correctly.
However, the jobs do not respond to the 'Build whenever a SNAPSHOT dependency is built' trigger. This means that I can only 'pull' the build of a top-level project - whereas I want these to be built when the lower-level dependencies are modified.
I am told that this (Jenkins) trigger will only work within a 'withMaven' step, and only when 'mvn' is called within a 'sh' step - and I've shown that it does work in this case. BUT I can't use the Jenkins Artifactory plugin inside the withMaven step.
I have looked at the maven-artifactory-plugin (pushing the responsibility into the maven build), and this might be the way to go ...
I wondered if anyone has managed to configure/use these tools successfully in this environment - and, if so, what combination of maven/jenkins plugins did you use?
Thanks
tim

Answer (score 1):

I've had to use a combined approach, but this seems to work :
All Maven projects use 'withMaven' to build and deploy with the pom.xml.
Any projects which need more complex processing also have a separate Jenkinsfile, which uses the Jenkins Artifactory plugin. This allows the capture of the BuildInfo.
I found there was no way to get my desired result using any other combination of plugins.
G'luck

Comment: It was actually quite frustrating in finding any documentation on the use of withMaven and artifactory.  It seems like this should be a bigger issue.  I want to use  artifactory to resolve and deploy artifacts, so I need to use rtMAven.  I want to trigger downstream builds that depend on the artifact being built, so I need to use withMaven.  Ughhh.